# java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading from file

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I have this issue that everytime I erase a line from my .txt file the code breaks and shows the message that is in the title.
My scanner reads a file with three elements in each line and stores it into an ArrayList.
If I don't change the file, it works. If I add another line, it works.
For some reason it crashes only when I erase a line.
This is a part of my code:

```
private ArrayList <Object> readObjects (String filename) 
    {
    ArrayList <Object> storeObjects = new ArrayList();      
        File file = new File(filename);
        try 
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                Object objectTemp = new Object();
                objectTemp.set(scanner.next(), scanner.next(), scanner.nextInt());
                storeObjects.add(objectTemp);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }      
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
        return storeObjects;
}
```

I changed the names of the objects and the arrayList to make it easier to read for you. Hopefully it helped.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a debug on which of the `scanner.next...` calls it is throwing an error.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you provided the file contents that you are trying to read. Also, i don't understand when exactly do you remove the line (like while it is read or manually).
if you try to do it while reading the file, then i would guess it is
`scanner.hasNextLine()` throwing the exeption.

Comment: How did you get it to compile? `objectTemp.set(scanner.next(), scanner.next(), scanner.nextInt());` isn't going to work as Object doesn't have a `set` method.

Comment: Are you by any chance leaving a newline char in the file when you "erase" a line? If so, your hasNextLine() will pass as true because it will read the new line char but the scanner.next() calls will fail because there would not be 3 items on the line. It would help if you could post your file and perhaps the file after you "erase" a line.

Comment: @Justine why not just make that the answer, you know thats what he did

Comment: @Justine , you made me feel stupid haha. You were absolutely right. Thanks! And thanks to everyone else who helped!